# exporting data in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, export-to-excel

i am trying to export data from the database I created in SQL Server 2012 so that I may take it to school and copy it all over to the main server there. I was shown how to do it on campus in the computer lab but whenever I right click the table and go for Tasks>Export There is not an option for Tasks. I also couldn't just generate the script I had to Right click table, Script Table as>Create to>New Query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click at the database node in SSMS Object Explorer (you're probably right-clicking a table node which wouldn't have "Export") (I assume you're talking about SQL Server Management Studio)

Here's a screenshot (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.2531.0):

[image]

Comment: I am talking about SQL Server. But I still do not see Export

Comment: what version of SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on database->click attack-> selct your database...

Make sure that data base backup should be make from that system... then only it will work.. if you copy from other sysytem means it wont work..